# Fetching data in useEffect with an array as dependency should only be called on new elements

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have an array, which is given as prop into my component named `Child`. Now, every time a new item is added to the array a fetch against an API should be made.

This array is held in a component named `Parent` using the `useState` hook. Whenever I want to add a new item, I have to recreate the array, since I'm not allowed to mutate it directly.

I tried to simplify my use case in the following code snippet:

```
const Parent = () => {
    const [array, setArray] = useState([]);

    ///...anywhere
    setArray(a => [...a, newItem]);

    return <Child array={array} />;
}

const Child = ({ array }) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        array.forEach(element => {
            fetch(...);    
        });
    }, [array]);

    return ...;
}
```

Now, my question is: How can I achieve to fetch new data from my API only for the new element but not for the whole array again?

I hope I described my issue good enough. If anything is unclear or missing, let me know.

Comment: your child component should receive only those items which need to be fetched

Comment: @tklepzig updated my answer with a second alternative in case you want to keep your existent structure.

Answer (score 1):

How about instead fetching the API data in `Parent` and just passing the end result to `Child`? That refactoring would provide some benefits:

- `Parent` [owns the items array state](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) and knows when and where a new item is added. That makes an incremental `fetch` very easy. You also get division of [container and presentational components](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0) for free.
- The fetched API data is related to the items array. You probably want to use them together in some way (save api data as state, combine them, etc.). This constellation would promote [derived state](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html), which is a more error prone pattern.

Something like following example could already do what you want - add an item via `onClick` (or somehow else), fetch its data and pass the whole array down to Child:

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [array, setArray] = useState([]);

  return (
    <div onClick={addItem}>
      <Child array={array} />;
    </div>
  );

  function addItem(e) {
    const item = createItemSomehow(...)
    fetch(...).then(data => setArray([...array, { item, data }]));
  }
};
```

Update:

If you want to keep your structure and API as is, an alternative would be to memoize the previous arrays prop in your Child with a [`usePrevious`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-get-the-previous-props-or-state) hook and look for item changes.

```
const Child = ({ array }) => {
  const prevArray = usePrevious(array);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (array !== prevArray && array.length) {
      //fetch(...)
      console.log(`fetch data for index ${array.length - 1}`);
    }
  });
  return (...);
};

function usePrevious(value) {
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  });
  return ref.current;
}
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-57621269-6vc7j)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll have a look into it!

Answer (score 0):

You could, for example, keep a list of previously fetched items.

```
const Child = ({ values }) => {

  const [fetched, setFetched] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    values.forEach(v => {
      if (!fetched.includes(v)) {
        setFetched(fetched => [...fetched, v]);
        fetch(v);
      }
    });
  }, [values, logged]);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-colden-sfpff